# Server wasn't able to start properly. error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'register')

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, migration, strapi

I am trying to migrate Strapi v3 with MongoDB to Strapi v4 with Postgres. I am following the official documentation https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/migration/v3-to-v4/data/mongo and installed the following dependencies:

- npm install strapi-connector-bookshelf@3.6.9 knex@0.21.19
- npm install pg@8.7.3

But when I try to run the Strapi I am getting the error (Server wasn't able to start properly. error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'register')). If anybody knows how to solve this error please reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure strapi-connector-bookshelf is the same version as your strapi package